# Server-Client inconsistent results

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, networking

Myself and another group member are responsible for creating the multiplayer aspect of the game. We are following a Server Client style in order to do this. We are able to connect the Server and the clients, and we send 4 messages to the client from the server. When using 2 clients, one client would receive the 4 Strings but the second would receive one string that is a combination of all 4 with white squares in between, sometimes with parts of the message cut off.

What could the cause be for the two clients to have different results, one receiving the correct 4 message and the other receiving one that is a combination of all 4?

MainServer acts as the host of the game, contains the server socket and the client connections.
Each Client is connected to a Server class and its the Server that talks to the MainServer

```
public class MainServer {

    public GameManager game;
    public Server[] connections; //Array of connected players if server is running.
    public int playerID = 1001;
    public ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int maxPlayers;
    public MainServer(GameManager game, int maxPlayers){
        this.game = game;   
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
    }

    public synchronized void runServer(int port){ //As it stands, having the game in server mode will dedicate it to server mode totally.
        try {
            int nclients = 0;
            connections = new Server[maxPlayers];
            //Await connections.
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("GAME NOW IN SERVER MODE"+ " Port: "+port+" URL: "+ss.getInetAddress()); 
            while (idList.size() != maxPlayers) { //WHile there are still open players slots
                //Wait for a socket
                //System.out.println("MainServer, before ss.accept()");
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("ACCEPTED CONNECTION FROM: " + s.getInetAddress());  

                connections[nclients] = new Server(s, playerID);
                idList.add(playerID);
                playerID++;
                connections[nclients].start();
                nclients++;
            }

            for (Server s : connections){
                System.out.println(s.playerID);
                if(s.dout==null){System.out.println("dout is null for server "+s.playerID);}
                s.dout.writeUTF("BEGINGAME");
                for (int i : idList){
                    s.dout.writeUTF(Integer.toString(i));
                }
                s.dout.writeUTF("ENDLIST");
            }


        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("I/O error: " + e.getMessage());
        } 

    }


public class Server extends Thread {
    public final Socket socket;
    public DataInputStream din;
    public DataOutputStream dout;
    public int playerID;

    public Server(Socket sock, int ID) {
        this.socket = sock;
        playerID = ID;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dout.writeInt(playerID);
            dout.flush();

            String frmClient = "", toClient = "";

            while (!frmClient.equals("stop")) {
                frmClient = din.readUTF();

                //System.out.println("client says: " + frmClient);
                //toClient = frmClient + " :Reply From Server";
                toClient = frmClient;

                sendToAll(toClient);
                dout.flush();
            }
            din.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Server I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public void sendToAll(String msg) throws IOException {
        for (Server s : GameManager.server.connections) {
            if (s != null && s.dout != null) {
                s.dout.writeUTF(msg);

            }
        }
    }
}

public class Client extends Thread {

    public DataOutputStream output;
    public DataInputStream input;

    private GameManager game;

    private String address;
    private int port;
    public int playerID;
    public ArrayList<String> allIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Socket s;
    //
    String l="";
    //

    public ArrayList<String> outBuff = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> inBuff = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Client(String add, int por, GameManager game) {
        address = add;
        port = por;
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void run() {     
        System.out.println("CLIENT");
        try {
            s = new Socket(address,port);
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            String toServ = "";
            String frmServ = "";

            playerID = input.readInt();

            while (!toServ.equals("stop")) {

                toServ = "";
                if(outBuff.size()>0){
                toServ = outBuff.remove(0);}

                if (toServ != null){
                    output.writeUTF(toServ);
                    output.flush();
                }

                frmServ = input.readUTF();


                if(frmServ.length()>0){
                    System.out.println(frmServ+" :test");}              
                if (frmServ != null&&frmServ.length()>0){
                    if (frmServ.equals("BEGINGAME")){
                        //System.out.println("2");
                        while (!frmServ.equals("ENDLIST")){
                            frmServ = input.readUTF();
                            if (!frmServ.equals("BEGINGAME")&&!frmServ.equals("ENDLIST")&&frmServ.length()>0){
                                System.out.println(frmServ+" :Adding to allIds");
                                allIds.add(frmServ);    
                            }                       
                        }

                        game.beginGame(allIds);

                    }
                    if(!frmServ.equals("BEGINGAME")||!frmServ.equals("ENDLIST")){
                        inBuff.add(frmServ);                        
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < inBuff.size() - 1; i++){
                    game.applyUpdateFromServer(inBuff.remove(i)); //Possible temporary solution, may cause lag because this thread is going into main game and performing tasks
                }


            }

            output.close();
            s.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Client I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you possibly format this mess properly.

Comment: And ask an actual question.  You have not asked a question or indicated what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

TCP does not maintain message boundaries. Sometimes the individual "messages" sent by your server will be received one at a time by a client; sometimes not. If multiple messages are sent in quick succession to a client, the sending system (I mean here the operating system not your server program) will bundle them into a single TCP segment and deliver them to the other system as a single unit. Even if that doesn't happen, the receiving system may end up aggregating several received messages and delivering them via a single receive call to the client.

You must always impose your own message protocol boundaries atop the logical stream TCP provides. That generally means either (a) putting a "record separator" (newline, zero byte, whatever) between records, or (b) putting a header at the beginning of each record indicating its length.